# direct standard error to same file and standard output?

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have something like

```
f=open('out.txt','w')
print >>f,  'action=%r'%action
```

in one of my Python programs. Is it possible to direct standard error to the same file as standard output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this...

```
import sys

f = open("error.log", "w")
sys.stderr = f            
print "raising exception"
raise Exception, "find this in error.log"
```

Or to answer your question more directly,

```
import sys
f = open("logall.txt", "w")
sys.stderr = f
sys.stdout = f
print "find this in logall.txt"
raise Exception, "find this in logall.txt"
```

Although I don't necessarily recommend the latter.

Comment: If you want to write to a file, I think it's better to just write to that file directly with f.write(), rather than making a global change like sys.stdout = f, which affects all print statements. Probably just my opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

You might just say this:

```
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
```

But I'd wager if your script will ever be maintained by someone else, you might cause some confusion. Rather than doing this inside the script, would it be an acceptable solution to do it from the calling shell?

```
myscript 2>&1
```